# Check contraint allowing only certain characters

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to create a column in Firebird (2.5) in a way, that it:

- cannot be NULL
- must be exactly 16 characters
- can only contain numbers and lowercase letters `a`-`f`

I could solve the first and second restriction.

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ADD NEW_COLUMN CHAR(16) NOT NULL CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(VALUE)) = 16)
```

I would prefer to not use triggers for the third requirement, but a check constraint - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use [SQL regexes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-predicates.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto)?

```
CHECK (value SIMILAR TO '[a-f0-9]{16}')
```

These were introduced in Firebird 2.5, and, conveniently for your purpose, must match the entire string.  (That is, they're "anchored" at both ends of the search space.)

Comment: Working fine, I just had to change `a-z` to `a-f`. I wasn't aware of the fact, that it was already introduced in 2.5, always thought of it as a new firebird 3 feature.